# How to effectively interact with a SQL database from python using a django-like structure?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Is there any Django like python package that would allow interaction with a MySQL database through a powerful structure (like models, managers, querysets, ...)?

I'm looking for something that would handle relations nicely like Django but connecting directly to the MySQL server, without having a full structure around.

**EDIT**
I don't want to explicitly redefine models in another ORM. I'm hoping some package could infer the relations from the already existing MySQL.

**EDIT 2**
A Django server is already running and the models exist. The goal is to access the database bypassing Django (for example to give access to only certain tables using a SQL user with only partial access) but using a nice pyton structure and not raw SQL.

Comment: peewee ? http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm trying to avoid setting-up an ORM, I already use Django.

Comment: Then what's your question actually ??? If the point is to generate Django ORM models from an existing database, this is documented : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: A Django server is already running and the models exist. The goal is to access the database bypassing Django (for example to give access to only certain tables using a SQL user with only partial access) but using a nice pyton structure and not raw SQL.

Comment: Please __edit your question__.

Comment: To the person who answered "SQL Alchemy" and removed the answer, it looks like exactly what I was looking for (especially the automap feature). I'll wait a while and re-post that answer to accept it.